# Django en Render *error* (2002, "No se puede conectar al servidor MySQL local a través del socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

Tags: mysql, django

subí mi proyecto de Django en Render y me da este error, parece que no puede conectarse con la BD.. pero no estoy seguro de que podría estar ocurriendo configure el setings.py como lo pone en la documentación de dj-base-url que es la librería para conectar la BD con Render... o eso entendí.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': dj_database_url.config(
# Feel free to alter this value to suit your needs.
    default='mysql://root:1234@localhost:3306/laboratorio', 
    conn_max_age=600    )}
```